# not updating the sql database

Tags: php, sql

i wrote the following code,but its not updating the database,,its a part of a script and it cease to work..cant find a way around it .. need suggestions

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('xxxxxxxx');
if (!$link) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("xxx", $link);


$usernames='aneeshxx';
echo $usernames;

$update = "INSERT sanjana SET $name ='$usernames'";
mysql_query($update, $link);

$update1 = "INSERT INTO sanjana (name)VALUES ($usernames)";
mysql_query($update1, $link);


?>
```

Comment: `mysql_ error()` and `mysql_ errno()` are your best friends...

Comment: Please, for you self, stop using mysql functions!!! You have PDO, MySQLi and a lot of abstractions layers with ORM, Object Mapping and more!!!! mysql functions sucks.

Answer (score 3):

```
$update = "INSERT sanjana SET $name ='$usernames'";
```

this probably is meant as an [UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html) statement, so for an update it should be

```
$update = "UPDATE sanjana set name = '$usernames'";
```

I put `name` and not `$name` due to your second query and not seeing `$name` being defined anywhere. Be aware that this will change the value in the column `name` of every row in the `sanjana` table to the value of $usernames, normally a statement such as this gets limited by [conditions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/expressions.html), e.g. `WHERE userid = 33`

```
$update1 = "INSERT INTO sanjana (name) VALUES ($usernames)";
```

for an [INSERT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) statement it needs to have the values quoted so

```
$update1 = "INSERT INTO sanjana (name) VALUES ('$usernames')";
```

Be wary that this way of putting variables directly into your query string makes you vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), to combat this please use the [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) extensions, they both protect you from injection by providing you with [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) ; plain old mysql_* is not recommended for use anymore.

using pdo you'd use prepared statements like this

```
<?php
// we got $usernames from wherever you define it

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=mydb;host=localhost','username','password');

// to insert
$statement = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO `sanjana` (name) VALUES (:name)');
// the following replaces :name with $usernames in a safe manner, defeating sql injection
$statement->bindParam(':name',$usernames);
$statement->execute(); // it is done


// to update
$statement = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE `sanjan` SET `name` = :name');
$statement->bindParam(':name',$usernames);
$statement->execute(); // it is done
```

so as you can see protecting your code from malicious input is not hard and it even makes your SQL statements a lot easier to read. Did you notice that you didn't even need to quote your values in the SQL statement anymore? Prepared statements take care of that for you! One less way to have an error in your code.

Please do read up on it, it will save you headaches. PDO even has the advantage that it's database independent, making it easier to use another database with existing code.

Answer (score 2):

The right update sql clause is like so:

```
UPDATE table
SET column = expression;
```

OR

```
UPDATE table
SET column = expression
WHERE predicates;
```

[SQL: UPDATE Statement](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/update.php)

Your query should be like this:

```
$update = "UPDATE sanjana SET $name ='$usernames'";
mysql_query($update, $link);
```

Of course you need to specify a row to update (id), other wise, the whole table will set column `$name` to `$usernames`.

**UPDATE:**

Because you are inserting a data in empty table, you should first execute $update1 query then execute $update query. `UPDATE` clause will make no change/insert on empty table.

Answer (score 2):

Problem 1:  use the correct "insert into" (create new record) vs. "update" (modify existing record)

Problem 2: It's good practice to create your SQL string *before* you call mysql_query(), so you can print it out for debugging

Problem 3: It's also good practice to detect errors

EXAMPLE:

```
<?php
  $link = mysql_connect('xxxxxxxx')
    or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

  mysql_select_db("xxx", $link);

  $usernames='aneeshxx';
  $sql = "INSERT INTO sanjana (name) VALUES ('" . $usernames + ")";
  echo "sql: " . $sql . "...<br/>\n";
  mysql_query($sql, $link)
    or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: BTW: Harald Brinkhof is absolutely correct about the need to "protect" your server by using "prepared statements" rather than raw SQL strings (SQL strings built from directly from web input being *extremely* vulnerable to *very* dangerous "SQL Injection" attacks). ["PHP Data Objects"](http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/PDO-Prepared-Statement-P550.html) (PDO) is a great way to mitigate this risk.

Answer (score 0):

You have INSERT keyword for your update SQL, this should be changed to UPDATE:

```
$update = "UPDATE sanjana SET $name ='$usernames'";
```

Comment: its an empty table,i am inserting data